# jQuery if not exist

Tags: jquery, cookies

This means "**if exist**"

```
if($.cookie("movies_list")) {
// do something
}
```

How to write "**if not exist**" without changing the structure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prepend the not operator `!`

```
if(! $.cookie("movies_list")) {
// do something
}
```

**[! Operator](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsoprNot.htm)**